# Converting AOP xml config to Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

I have the following xml based AOP code

```
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="handlerMethodAop"
            expression="execution(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping * *(..))" />

        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="handlerMethodAop"
            advice-ref="handlerMethodAdvice" />
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="handlerMethodAop"
            advice-ref="handlerMethodThrowsAdvice" />
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="handlerMethodAop"
            advice-ref="warningThrowsAdvice" />
    </aop:config>
```

The values in the advice-ref attributes are beans I have declared elsewhere.

How can I convert this to Java Config? 90% of my app is already using Java config so I don't need a lesson in the basics of how to do that, specifically just how to configure this AOP stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use advice declarations in `@Aspect` components instead of advisors.
2. Use declarative `@Configuration` elements such as `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` instead of XML configuration.

See [Spring AOP manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Comment: I do not have access to the classes being used for aspects, so annotations will not work for me. XML it is!

Comment: What are you talking about? You said you want to convert XML config to Java and now you say "XML it is"?! Is this a joke?

Comment: Not a joke, just realizing that Java config is impossible for my situation because I do not have the source for the advisors being used in the xml. I thought this might be the case, and your answer confirmed it.